# Additional Validation using aspnet Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am using additional validation using AspnetIdentity but it is not working gives me this error. Here is my code for interface.

```
using Health.BLL.CustomModels.UserModels;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Health.BLL.AuthRepository
{
    public interface IAuthRepository
    {
        Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(UserModel userModel);
        Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password);
        Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(string userid);
        Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync<TUser>(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user) where TUser : class;
    }
}
```

For error reference please see the below image.

> The type 'TUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the
>   generic type or method 'UserManager'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'TUser' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXQxl.png)

Comment: You need to look at the definition of `UserManager<TUser>` and copy the constraint for `TUser` to your method definition's constraint for `TUser`

Comment: Please add error messages as text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type passed to UserManager needs to implement the interface `IUser<TKey>`, where TKey is your user's key type, it can be string, int, etc.

So, assuming that your user key type (TKey) is string, change the contract of ValidateAsync to:

```
Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync<TUser>(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user) 
    where TUser : class, IUser<string>;
```

Refer to the documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn468199(v=vs.108

Try it, and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad, maybe there's something wrong with the Nuget Package you're using?...

I've tried to reproduced your error, but everything works fine! I tested your code in a project with Asp.Net Core 2.2, and in another with Asp.Net Core 3.0/3.1.

For the project in Asp.Net Core 2.2, I installed the Nuget Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore Version 2.2.3.

And for the project made in Asp.Net Core 3.0/3.1, I installed the same Nuget Package but version 3.1.3.

And the code that I used to test:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public interface IAuthRepository
    {
        Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password);
        Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(string userid);
        Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync<TUser>(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user) where TUser : class;
    }
}
```

Maybe you should edit your question with the Version of the Asp.Net Framework you're using in your project, and the Nuget Package for Identity that you're using.

Comment: I get it. Well I am not using aspnet identity core. I am using simple aspnet identity Framework using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.0. How can i achieve this using without aspnet identity core?